# Pass data from MainView to ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I have this storyboard:

[image]
and this code:

```
var actualVisibleView : String? = nil

func showSubViewInContainerView(view: String, parms: String?){
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: view)

        systemContainerView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)

        if view == "ConceptGalleryView" {

        }

        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        self.actualVisibleView = view
        print("OPEN: \(view)")
    }
```

From the left menu, I open various views in this containerview using the code:

```
showSubViewInContainerView(view: "View1", parms: "1")
showSubViewInContainerView(view: "View2", parms: "2")
showSubViewInContainerView(view: "View3", parms: "3")
showSubViewInContainerView(view: "View4", parms: nil)
```

For example, I have a call to ConceptGalleryView.swift:

```
var idGallery = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

How can I save the idGallery parameter from the showSubViewInContainerView function - parms?

Comment: you are instantiating a view controller but mentioned about view. How is that possible ? Besides your ConceptGalleryView has viewDidLoad method. It isn't possible also. Is your ConceptGalleryView actually a subclass of UIViewController or UIView ?

Answer (score -1):

past it in: ViewController bottom.

You have to create public variable so you can all it from view controller to another:

```
class variables
{
    static var name: String = ""
}
```

And print out the variable:

```
print("\(variables.name)")
```

Comment: public variables I would not like to use. I would say some more "professional" solution :)